# How do I pass a value to a PHP script using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to learn web design with a search function using MySql. I want make it to 2 steps selection however, I have run into a problem which really confuses me since I don't have a strong background to design. I am trying to be as specific as possible to make the question clear.

**test.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>count</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dbstyle.css">
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'> 
</script>

</head>
<body>

<form id="serc" method="post" action="">
<input type="radio" value="typeA" name="comments" onclick="expr()">Good
<input type="radio" value="typeB" name="comments" onclick="expr()">Bad
</form>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" style="visibility:hidden">
<p>please select reason:</p>
<input type="checkbox" class="check" name="checkbox[]" value="COL 8">aaa<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="check" name="checkbox[]" value="COL 9">bbb<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="check" name="checkbox[]" value="COL 10" >ccc<br />
<button id="aaa" type="submit" class="butt" name="sub2" style="visibility:hidden">Submit</button>
</form>

<?php
$comm = $_POST["gender"];
$reas = $_POST["checkbox"];

if($comm){$respond = $_POST['comments'];
    echo $respond;
}

<script src="limit.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**limit.js**

```
//click to get Value
$("input[type='Radio']").click(function(){
    var radioValue = $("input[name='comments']:checked").val();
    $("#serc").css("display", "none");
    $("#form1").css("visibility", "visible");
});

//limit multiple selection up to 4
$("input:checkbox").click(function() {
    var bol = $("input:checkbox:checked").length;
    if(bol == 4){
        $("input:checkbox").not(":checked").attr("disabled",bol);
        $("#aaa").css("visibility", "visible");
    }
    else {
        $("#aaa").css("visibility", "hidden");
        $("input:checkbox").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
});

// return value
function expr()
{
    var radioValue = $("input[name='comments']:checked").val();
    var dataTosend= radioValue;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: dataTosend,
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data)
        },
    });
}
```

The function will be:

First stage select from radio item, `onclick` use jQuery to hide the selection items and also get `radioValue` from the jQuery by Ajax way to send to php use.

Second stage select 4 items from checkbox, and submit to run search field.

I expect load the `radioValue` back to php as a variable but seems it didn't get the value.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are trying to submit when user clicks either Good or Bad radio button.. is that correct? The Submit handler is just considering the Good/Bad radio button & not the checkboxes below.. is this correct?

Comment: I am trying to make the submit button considering the checkbox only, and its working . But before that the radio button is unable to got the value(typeA/typeB) while i click the radio (which there is no submit).

Comment: `onclick="expr()"` is there on the typeA/typeB radio buttons which means you want to submit as soon as the option is clicked. Only submit button is `name="sub2"` which is inside the 2nd form and not in this. Is that how you want it?

Comment: Use your browser console "Network" tab to monitor the ajax call. You can verify if the data is being submitted or not after examining the call.

Comment: I was trying to got the value back to php when i click onclick="expr()" but not submit, just get the value "typeA" from the button, my jQuery had defined the action after i click the button, and i just want to send the value "typeA/B" back to php so that it can be use to define other function. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must send data using key value pair like this:

```
    function expr(){
    var radioValue = $("input:radio[name='comments']").val();
    var dataTosend= {'radioValue': radioValue};
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: dataTosend,
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data)
        },
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply, I tried to recall the value but it seems unable to recall by this way: "echo $radioValue; " but it seems not return the value after i clicked the radio item. or do I misunderstood something that caused this issue?

Comment: I also tried to send to an empty php file and it jumps an empty box when it runs alert(data). Any comments will be gratitude. Thanks again

Comment: Your welcome .Are you can print the selected radio value in console before send to ajax?It seems your select not working.try this again : var radioValue = $("input:radio[name='comments']").val();

Comment: Tried to do that, When I clicked the radio the alert shows up and print "localhost says with empty box". Seems like the value from the radio (typeA/B) wasn't able to load before ajax. Thinking about how to fix it...at the moment.

Comment: by this way your PHP should get the radio button value in `$_REQUEST['radioValue']` or `$_POST['radioValue']` is it showing blank there?

Comment: Yes it get with $_REQUEST['radioValue'] or $_POST['radioValue'].But it shouldn't be blank.to check that your php side is work fine, you can set var dataTosend= {'radioValue': 2};   manualy, if this return right then your JavaScript code's must be edited.

Comment: @techie_28 Yes I tried to do that way, it is showing blank on the screen.

Comment: @Naser Nourani I tried to replace the line by set var to 2, onclick in the box shows empty as wells, maybe is it because i haven't declare something beforehand?

Comment: use the Dev options of the browsers.Press `F12`. Select `Network` tab & click on the radio button  The ajax call should show along with the sent param,click and examine the request/response of the call. Also put a `console.log(dataTosend)` after the var to see if the value is coming in the variable or not.

Comment: I look once again and i see that you send request to index.php, is this file exists?

Comment: @ Naser Nourani yes this file is exist

Comment: @ techie_28 Thanks for the method. By this way I receive" Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (test.js:4)"  in the beginning. While I click the 
"Uncaught ReferenceError: expr is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick (test.js:14)"

Comment: I check that and the problem is that you forgot to close php end tag ( ?> ) in line 35.

Comment: @ Naser Nourani  Thanks for point out, I checked that and realized it is one of the reason. After revised I still not able to catch the code :( , Not knowing where is the major problem from.